# Crittercism on Android with NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, crittercism

I'm attempting to use the example code from Crittercism found in their documentation: http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#other-tasks  I get the callback, but after I've forced an exception in my C++ code I always get false from the boolean didCrashOnLastLoad.  Does Crittercism support crashes in NDK?

Answer (score 4):

[Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) does support NDK crashes and this callback does look for both NDK and Android SDK crashes occurring.

If you go to this [download](http://docs.crittercism.com/downloads/downloads.html) link you'll see next to Android an Android NDK download, this will download the latest version of the NDK library.

You need to install the NDK .jar file versus the regular SDK as it provides the added NDK functionality, otherwise there is no difference between the two .jar files. This was separated out to give developers the option of support since it does increase the Library's size.

One note to keep in mind, NDK support is currently covered in the paid plans and not on the Basic plan. See the plan options [here](http://www.crittercism.com/pricing/).

Comment: I am using the NDK version, but 4.4.0.  Oh, and I did email Crittercism since we have a plan and I have a ticket, just was seeing if anyone else could help with it while I wait.

Comment: Sure, the above should clear things up for the callback, though if you're having trouble with the plan not giving you permission, then Crittercism support was the right place to go. :)