# Crittercism catching native exceptions in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, crittercism

I'm helping develop an app that uses a 3rd party library which uses the NDK. However, whenever I try to enable NDK reporting, I don't see any actual crashes in the live alerts:

```
        CrittercismConfig config = new CrittercismConfig();
        config.setNdkCrashReportingEnabled(true);
        Crittercism.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "myCrittercismId", config);
```

How do I capture native crashes with Crittercism?

Alternatively, we do have this other library that can capture native crashes and dump them into a file. However, I couldn't find a way to upload just a raw file with a Handled Exception for Crittercism. How is this usually done?  Where you want to upload custom data that is associated with a crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is a duplicate of:

[Crittercism on Android with NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959050/crittercism-on-android-with-ndk/23961127#23961127)

Crittercism doesn't currently provide a way to pass along custom crash data for native crashes since our system currently uses a particular process for [server-side symbolication](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#configuring-android-ndk-symbolication). Without this symbolication, the raw file won't be much help anyway.

The following code is actually legacy from older libraries and no longer necessary with the latest:

```
config.setNdkCrashReportingEnabled(true);
```

Lastly, make sure that the other crash handler isn't interfering with Crittercism, otherwise you won't see any reports on the portal. If you check didCrashOnLastLoad (following these [instructions](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#callbacks-and-user-data-reports)) this should check to see if a crash file was created where Crittercism stores them to get sent.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common causes is that you're using a version of the Android which does not have NDK support.  We do have a separate NDK crash reporting library which is available for download here:

http://docs.crittercism.com/downloads/downloads.html

You can also view the complete instructions for including Android NDK support here:
http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/How-do-I-include-NDK-support